# Worker package disfunction when importing postgresql package

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I'm trying to use the Worker package and the PostgreSQL package.

I'm not sure why but if I run the example in
https://diegorochablog.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/worker-dart-concurrent-programming-does-not-have-to-be-hard/
After changing nothing but adding an `import` statement: `import 'package:postgresql/postgresql.dart';`,  The example stops working (the task's `execute` is not called).

Dart VM version: 1.17.0-dev.4.1 (Thu May 19 11:21:39 2016) on "macos_x64".

### pubspec.yaml

```
name: fibFuturesConcu
version: 0.0.1
description: A simple console application.
dependencies:
  worker: any
```

### Update

Apparently it does not happen with the stable version of Dart (1.16.0).

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/worker

Comment: I see. Can't help with your problem though.

Comment: Can you include content of your pubspec.yaml? Also what version of dart do you use?

Comment: @PiKos I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: @AlonAmir Do you have the same problem on a latest stable version of Dart (1.16.0)?

Comment: @PiKos Just checked, does not happen in Stable, so I guess it's a bug...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone when using Dart Stable 1.16.